# Suppress dialog caused by logging in via URL

Tags: security, http, url, networking, web

I have a link on my web-page which automatically logs in through a generic username/password for the purposes of a demo, eg :

```
https://username:password@www.example.com
```

A dialog box shows up which says "You are now logging in as username. Is this correct?"

How can I remove this dialog to allow me to log into this web-page as cleanly as possible?

I've considered using JS to resolve the issue but there must be a simpler way?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using HTTP authentication in the first place?

Comment: @ircmaxell For the storyboard, the demo puts the user in the "shoes" of another user. In other words, it was a ridiculous requirement from management :)

Comment: How is the dialog created (framework,etc..)?

Comment: @Stefan It is a HTTP-Auth window, created directly by IIS/Apache/the HTTPD.

Comment: @SimonKiely Don't use HTTP auth then. If you need to masquerade as another user, use a normal authentication system. I don't see why it *has* to be part of the URL. And if you want to make it emailable, you could make an encrypted token which is appended to the URL to tell your system how to authenticate the user...

Comment: @ircmaxwell I don't have authority over the remote server so can't change what is being used - and trust me, I have tried :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using http basic authentication which is a protocol that is a part of http. The username and password is sent to the web server and verified before your web page is loaded.

It is not the web page that creates this dialog, but your browser. It will be different for different browsers. Firefox creates a confirmation message when you provide the username and password in the address bar. Chrome will not create this confirmation message.

A javascript or any other kind of functionality in your web page would not be able to remove this message. The reason for this is that the message is created by the browser before the web page is actually loaded.